# how to use jquery append correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

I need to append new contents based on json file. Once I type it manually in the html it works with no problems but once I want to loop using jQuery each function it does not work. Note, I have check the looping method using alert function and it alert 2 times cause the json contents 2 objects but it seems to be an issue with the append function. Note, based on chrome inspect, the append function doesnt create the div inside the main div center it create each one and place them individually alone I am a noob in the front end development any suggestion for improving and best practice is appreciate it

HTML file

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="center"> 
         <div class="column middle"> <p id="text"></p>
             <a href="" id="link">More</a></div>
         <div class="column side">
             <img class="image" id="image" src="">
            </div>
        </div>           
</div>
```

The javascript file:

```
info = 
[
  {"details" : "this a text for examples",
   "link" : "www.google.com",
   "image" : "download.jpg"
},
{

    "details" : "this a text for",
    "link" : "www.google.com",
    "image" : "download.jpg"
}
]



$(document).ready(function(){

$.each(info, function(i,v) {
        $(".wrapper").append("<div class=\"center\">");
        $(".wrapper").append("<div class=\"column middle\"> <p id=\"text\" 
         </p>");
        $(".wrapper").append("<a href=\"\" id=\"link\">More</a></div>");
        $(".wrapper").append("<div class=\"column side\">");
        $(".wrapper").append("<img class=\"image\" id=\"image\" src=\"\">");
        $(".wrapper").append("</div>");
        $(".wrapper").append("</div>");

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = info[i].details;
        $("#link").attr("href",info[i].link); 
        $("#image").attr("src",info[i].image);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to duplicate `id` which does not work. Keep in mind the `id` attribute needs to be unique, so if you really need an `id`, you can append the index to make it unique.

Additionally, you can use `backticks` to keep the code clean and then use the second parameter for `$.each` to get the value, rather than accessing by their index.

```js
info = [{
    "details": "this a text for examples",
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "image": "download.jpg"
  },
  {

    "details": "this a text for",
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "image": "download.jpg"
  }
]



$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each(info, function(i, v) {
    $(".wrapper").append(`
       <div class="center">
        <div class="column middle"> 
          <p>${v.details}</p>
          <a href="${v.link}">More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column side">
           <img class="image" src="${v.image}">
        </div>
      </div>
       `);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="center">
    <div class="column middle">
      <p id="text"></p>
      <a href="" id="link">More</a></div>
    <div class="column side">
      <img class="image" id="image" src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template literal is you are using an ES6 supported browser.

### ES6

```js
let info = [{
  "details": "this a text for examples",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}, {
  "details": "this a text for",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}];

$(() => {
  $('.wrapper').append(info.map(renderContent));
});

function renderContent(data) {
  return `
    <div class="center">
      <div class="column middle">
        <p id="text">${data.details}</p>
        <a href="${data.link}" id="link">More</a></div>
      <div class="column side">
        <img class="image" id="image" src="${data.image}">
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

### ES5 or lower

If you are using ES5 or lower, you can use a library like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

```js
var info = [{
  "details": "this a text for examples",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}, {
  "details": "this a text for",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html());
  $('.wrapper').append(info.map(v => template(v)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.4.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="column middle">
      <p id="text">{{details}}</p>
      <a href="{{link}}" id="link">More</a></div>
    <div class="column side">
      <img class="image" id="image" src="{{image}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Or you can embed the template in a for-loop.

```js
var info = [{
  "details": "this a text for examples",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}, {
  "details": "this a text for",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html());
  $('body').append(template(info));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.4.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="wrapper">
    {{#each .}}
      <div class="center">
        <div class="column middle">
          <p id="text">{{details}}</p>
          <a href="{{link}}" id="link">More</a></div>
        <div class="column side">
          <img class="image" id="image" src="{{image}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

### Functional jQuery only

Be aware, I advise against assigning the same ID to multiple elements. This is a very important rule in DOM/HTML/XML.

```js
var info = [{
  "details": "this a text for examples",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}, {
  "details": "this a text for",
  "link": "www.google.com",
  "image": "download.jpg"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper').append(info.map(v => renderContent(v)));
});

function renderContent(data) {
  return $('<div>').addClass('center')
    .append($('<div>').addClass('column middle')
      .append($('<p>').attr('id', 'text').text(data.details))
      .append($('<a>').attr('id', 'link').attr('href', data.link).text('More')))
    .append($('<div>').addClass('column side')
      .append($('<img>').addClass('id').attr('id', 'image').attr('src', data.image)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using an ES6 compatible browser, you can just make one long string for each element, including the object values where appropriate:

```js
let info = [{
    "details": "this a text for examples",
    "link": "www.stackoverflow.com",
    "image": "profile.jpg"
  },
  {

    "details": "this a text for",
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "image": "download.jpg"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(info, function(i, v) {
    $(".wrapper").append('<div class="center">\
<div class="column middle"> <p>' + v.details + '</p>\
<a href="' + v.link + '" >More</a></div>\
<div class="column side">\
<img class="image" src="' + v.image + '">\
</div>\
</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to addclass using attr method in jQuery
'''$(".wrapper").attr('class','Column side')'''